# Server is not receiving cookie in the request that sent in the previous response

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cookies

we are adding security token as a cookie in the response in the server before returning data to the client(browser) when user logon first time and adding that cookie as header in $http in the browser. Our expectation is that all subsequent requests will be containing that token as Header and cookie and we are retrieving them in the server to authenticate the requests to avoid XSRF.

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie=new CookieHeaderValue("cookiename","value");
cookie.secure=true;
cookie.HTTPOnly=true;
Httpresponsemessage.headers.addcookies(cookie);
```

we are using following method to retrieve cookie `HTTPActionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies();`

this is working few times and few times it is not working. as per the logs, it seems that cookie is null randomly. when i verified the requests and response in the browser i can see the cookie and header.
Also,when i check the HTTPActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme, it is showing as http but not as HTTPS(our application runs over https). I'm assuming our LoadBalancer is stripping the S due to settings at server level but not sure if this could be causing the issue as server is receiving cookie sometimes.

can you please help me in understanding what could be the issue??

we are using WEBAPI at server and Angular at client side.